# html - Website layout resizing on zooming in and changing resolutions

Tags: html, css, layout, web

```html
<html>
<style>
body { background-color:#F1EEF2; }
header { 
width:800px; 
margin-left:auto; 
margin-right:auto;
}
layout {
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
}
nav.header {
width:800px; 
height:40px; 
background-color:#000000;
color:#fef8f0; 
}
nav.footer {
width:800px; 
height:30px; 
color:#fef8f0; 
}

footer { 
width:800px; 
height:80px; 
background:url(images/footer_beans.png) no-repeat #000000;
margin-left:auto; 
margin-right:auto;
}

span {
font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
font-size:11px;  
font-weight:bold; 
color:#c29a5f;
}
p.s1 {
font-family: sans-serif; 
font-size:15px; 
color:#ffffff;
margin:0px;
padding:10px 24px 0;
}
p.s2 {
font-family: sans-serif; 
font-size:15px; 
color:#000000;
margin:0px;
padding:12px 10px 15px 12px;
}
ul.header {
width:500px; 
margin:0;
padding:0;
padding-top:13px;
float:right; 
list-style-type:none; 
font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
font-size:11px; 
font-weight:bold;
}
ul.footer {
width:500px; 
float:right; 
list-style-type:none; 
margin: 0;
padding:0;
padding-top:47px;
font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
font-size:12px; 
font-weight:bold;
}
li {
float:left;
font-size:11px; 
font-weight:bold; 
margin:0;
}
a {
padding:8px;
color:#fef8f0; 
text-decoration:none;
}
section {
width:800px; 
margin:0 auto;
}
article { 
width:800px; 
height:600px;
}
#left, #right {
 background: #000000;
 position: fixed;
 }
 #left, #right {
  top: 0; bottom: 0;
  width: 10px;
  }
  #left { left: 265; }
  #right { right: 265; }
  
#hm_topleft {width:434px; height:300px; float:left;}

#hm_topright {width:366px; height:300px; float:left; background:#570401;  margin=0; overflow=hidden;}

#hm_content {width:800px; height:300px; margin:auto; float:left; background-color:#000000;}

#hm_contentbox {width:760px; height:130px; margin:25px; background:#F1EEF2; border:3px solid #000000;}
</style>
<div id="layout">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta charset=iso-8859-1>
<title>MAJID JORDAN - Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<nav class="header";>
  <ul class="header">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>|</li>
  <li><a href="#">Members</a>|</li>
  <li><a href="#">Albums</a>|</li>
  <li><a href="#">Gigs & Tours</a>|</li>
  <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</header>
<section  style="width:800px; margin:0 auto;">
<article style=" width:800px; height:600px; ">
<img src="C:\Users\jorda_000.JORDAN-PC\Pictures\Website\logo.jpg" width="200" height="170" alt="MAJID JORDAN"/>
<div
   style="
      padding: 10px;
      top: 10;
      right: 480;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      visibility: show;
   font-size:35px;">
<h1><center><font face="verdana"><strong>MAJID JORDAN</font></center</strong><h1>
</div>
<div id="hm_contentbox">
<p class="s2">Majid Jordan is a Canadian R&B duo, composed of singer Majid Al Maskati and producer Jordan Ullman. They are signed to OVO Sound, the record label co-founded by rapper Drake, producer Noah "40" Shebib and Oliver El-Khatib.
Jordan, originally from Toronto, and Majid, arriving in Toronto by way of Bahrain, met as students at the University of Toronto in 2011. Working between Ullman's dorm room and his parents' basement, they launched their first joint EP titled Afterhours on SoundCloud under their previous name Good People.</p>
</div>
<div
style="
position: absolute;
top: 390px;
right: 285px;
border: 3px solid black;">
<img src="C:\Users\jorda_000.JORDAN-PC\Pictures\Website\home.jpg" width="400" height="300" alt="MAJID JORDAN"/>
</div>
<button style="margin:auto;border-radius:10px;border:1px solid black;color:solid black;height:60px;width:300px;font-size:24px;position:absolute;top:400;left:300;"><strong>
Members
</button></strong>
<button style="margin:auto;border-radius:10px;border:1px solid black;color:solid black;height:60px;width:300px;font-size:24px;position:absolute;top:480;left:300;"><strong>
Albums & Songs
</button></strong>
<button style="margin:auto;border-radius:10px;border:1px solid black;color:solid black;height:60px;width:300px;font-size:24px;position:absolute;top:560;left:300;"><strong>
Gigs & Tours
</button></strong>
<button style="border-radius:10px;border:1px solid black;color:solid black;height:60px;width:300px;font-size:24px;position:absolute;top:640;left:300;"><strong>
Gallery
</button></strong>

<footer style="position:absolute;top:710;>
<nav class="footer">
<ul class="footer">
<li class="hf1"><a>Members </a>|</li>
<li class="hf1"><a>Albums & Songs </a>|</li>
<li class="hf1"><a>Gigs & Tours </a>|</li>
<li class="hf1"><a>Gallery</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</footer>
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm an extreme beginner when it comes to html, and I'm creating a small website on a band of my choice and it looks perfectly fine on the computer I used to create the website, but on another computer with a different resolution, the whole layout is messed up and objects are overlapping etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as like I said, I'm very new wit this language, if you need any more information I'll try and assist you.

Comment: Give you code or fiddle it.. get basic knowledge in bootstrapping so that you page will look alike in all resolutions

Comment: you have to make website responsive..so that it will work on every device like phone,ipad,laptop..refer http://getbootstrap.com/ for that

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You could of course Code your own solution, but this would be like reinventing the wheel and for beginners its really difficult. The most common solution is to use a CSS and/or JS Framework, like bootstrap or angularmaterial. This will not only give you the tools to make your site responsive with little to no effort it also has some cool design opportunities. You also don't need to worry about being restricted since you can "overwrite" some things in the framework with your own css Code.
For some Education you can look here:
http://getbootstrap.com/ ->Get Bootstrap (it's free)
http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/ -> some explanation to get a grasp on what you can do
 http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp -> a well written beginner friendly tutorial for bootstrap

If you are not convinced yet check this out:
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_theme_band.asp
If you need some further advice or some more detail on specific questions, just contact me.